# How to add enum and boolean statement in when expression

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to make an expression like this:

```
when(enum) {
EnumType && boolean ->
```

without moving the enum variable out of when expression like this:

```
when {
enum==EnumType && boolean ->
```

Comment: Why would you need that? Give us more details so we can actually help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post full code but I can do something like this

```
when(enum){
    EnumType -> {
      if(boolean) {
      }
    }
}
```

If you describe your problem with more code we can help you better